# Getting Error 400 when sending GET request with json field from one Cloud Run to another

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-cloud-run

I am trying to send a request from one Cloud Run service to another. Both are running on Flask. My issue is that there is an email field that I need to send as part of the body of both PUT and GET requests. I know GET doesn't usually have a body but I need to send it this way. However I keep getting an Error 400 (Bad Request). It works fine when I run the services on my local machine but this error starts to appear when on Cloud Run. Please help me figure out if there is a configuration or something I can change to get this to work.

```
@bigbox_routing_bp.route("/variants/", methods=["GET"])
@secure(
    scope=UserAccountType.INTERNAL,
    resource_type=ResourceType.VARIANT,
    permissions=[ProductPermissions.ALL, ProductPermissions.READ],
)
def get_variants():
    regexMatch = re.match(f"(.*)({request.path})(.*)", request.url)
    response = requests.get(
        url=f"{BIGBOX_URL}{regexMatch.group(2)}{regexMatch.group(3)}",
        json={"email": request.user.email},
    )
    return (response.json(), response.status_code)
```

Comment: Please include a minimal repro of the issue so that we may help. This could be a `curl` command or some code. Stating that something doesn't work is insufficient.

Comment: I have added the code I am using. This is what my GET request looks like.

Comment: Thank you! Please confirm some debugging. You need not include in your question. Does `url` contain the value you expect? What about `request.user.email`? Unless the backing service is public, you're going to need to authenticate the request too.

Comment: Also, if you're providing JSON (`GET` is okay), you'll need to add a header `content-type: application/json` and I think the JSON needs to be provided as `data` parameter not `json`!?

Comment: Apologies, I was mistaken. I think (!?) if you want to use `GET` with a JSON body with `requests`, you may need to use [`requests.request`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=requests.request#custom-verbs), i.e. `requests("get",url,data={"email":request.user.email})`

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I just found this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35876324#c5
Maybe Cloud Run doesn't allow GET requests with body field. Will have to ask their support team.

Comment: That issue is 5 years old and `urlfetch` is an App Engine specific service. It's possible that Cloud Run doesn't support `GET` with a body but I think it's unlikely as the request should be routed effectively unchanged by the Cloud LBs. You assert that it worked locally so your container image likely works too. Can you try `curl`'ing the container and reconstructiong your request: `curl --request GET --header "content-type: application/json" --data "{\"email\": \"${EMAIL}\"}" "${URL}` replacing as appropriate.